# Function with extra parameters from another function's input

Tags: r, function, scope

This is a relatively simply problem but I'm stumped. I am programming in R, but I don't think this problem is restricted to R. Below I've tried to write some simple code demonstrating the problem:

```
f1 = function(x) {
  return(a + x)
}

f2 = function(ftn) {
  return(ftn(1))
}

f3 = function(a) {
  return(f2(f1))
}
```

The Problem: If I call f3(2) [for example], f2(f1) is returned, and f2(f1) returns f1(a+1). But f1 does not recognize the value of 'a' that I put in f3, so the code doesn't work! Is there any way I can make it so that f1 recognizes the input into f3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R uses lexical scope, not dynamic scope.  Functions look up free variables (variables used but not defined within them) in the environment in which the function was defined.  `f1` was defined in the global environment so `a` is looked up in the global environment and there is no `a` there.  We can force `f1` to look up its free variables in the running instance of `f3` like this:

```
f3 = function(a) {
  environment(f1) <- environment()
  return(f2(f1))
}
```

This temporarily creates a new `f1` within `f3` with the desired environment.

Another possibility if `f1` is only needed within `f3` is to define `f1` there (rather than in the global environment):

```
f3 = function(a) {
   f1 = function(x) {
        return(a + x)
  }      
  return(f2(f1))
}
```

By the way, the last expression evaluated in a running function is returned so this could be written:

```
f3 <- function(a) {
      f1 <- function(x) a + x
      f2(f1)
}
```